# Using information involving multiple model parameters as a prior

Tags: bayesian, pymc

I am estimating a relatively simple linear equation of the following form:

$$
y = \beta_0 + \beta_1p + \beta_2t +\epsilon
$$

I would like to take a bayesian modelling approach, and have existing information that indicates that the ratio of two parameters would follow a certain distribution (I am using normal distribution as an example, but it can be different):

$$
\frac{\beta_1}{\beta_0} \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)
$$

Is there any way to capture this information as a prior for the above model?

I suppose if the prior was known for either $\beta_0$ or $\beta_1$ you could derive two seperate priors? Alternatively inverting the model could isolate a single parameter representing the above ratio - although it would not be preferable to do so.

If anyone is interested, see a related response regarding the implementation at the pymc3 discourse: https://discourse.pymc.io/t/constraint-or-prior-dependent-on-multiple-parameters/3934

Comment: The normal distribution is not a good model especially if $\beta_0$ can be 0. A Cauchy distribution could be better in that case.

Comment: Fair point, appreciate that recommendation.  Any suggestions on what approach to take more generally would be appreciated.

Comment: Bayesian modeling requires the determination or choice of a prior for all parameters, from which you can derive the prior on $\beta_1/\beta_0$. Note also that a Cauchy distribution is the distribution of a ratio of two Normal variates, which gives some weight to the choice suggested by Michael.

Comment: Ok so you are effectively suggesting I should guess the prior distribution for either β0 or β1 and then derive the remaining from the ratio distribution? I should make it clear that i know $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ of the ratio distribution